# AWS javascript SDK SES SendMail Illegal Address

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm attempting to send mail using AWS SES.

Here's the error I'm seeing:

```
{
    "message": "Illegal address",
    "code": "InvalidParameterValue",
    "time": "2017-06-02T03:12:37.110Z",
    "requestId": "544c6aee-4741-11e7-9cf5-a709f069aa99",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 73.04001529701054
}
```

Here's the request object being passed in to SendMail method of AWS.SES for javascript SDK.

```
{
    "Destination": {
        "BccAddresses": [],
        "CcAddresses": [],
        "ToAddresses": [
            "success@simulator.amazonses.com"
        ]
    },
    "Message": {
        "Body": {
            "Html": {
                "Charset": "UTF-8",
                "Data": "You have been removed from Kudo mailing list for account: bob@gmail.com"
            },
            "Text": {
                "Charset": "UTF-8",
                "Data": "You have been removed from Kudo mailing list for account: bob@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        "Subject": {
            "Charset": "UTF-8",
            "Data": "Kudo email removal"
        }
    },
    "ReplyToAddresses": [],
    "ReturnPath": "",
    "ReturnPathArn": "",
    "Source": "donotreply@kudo.io",
    "SourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:1xxxxxxxxxx2:identity/donotreply@kudo.io"
}
```

bob@gmail.com is verified on my account (which is still in sandbox mode).  donotreply@kudo.io is also verified on my account.

Edit:  I just tested it by using the test email option in SES and it worked...  still can't get it to send using the SDK though.

Comment: Why are you setting `SourceArn`?  Also, you say the sending address is verified -- but are you consistently using the same SES region in the console and with the API?  The regions are independent and if you're verified in us-west-2 but sending this to the us-east-1 endpoint... you see the problem there.

Comment: Ive tried both with and without using sourcearn.  That sourcearn is for the verified email address donotreply@kudi.io.  And yes, everything is running in the same region.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, the key is to remove the empty strings for ReturnPath and ReturnPathArn and SourceArn if you aren't using it.  Once I did that it worked.

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=787424&#787424

```
{
    "Destination": {
        "BccAddresses": [],
        "CcAddresses": [],
        "ToAddresses": [
            "success@simulator.amazonses.com"
        ]
    },
    "Message": {
        "Body": {
            "Html": {
                "Charset": "UTF-8",
                "Data": "You have been removed from Kudo mailing list for account: bob@gmail.com"
            },
            "Text": {
                "Charset": "UTF-8",
                "Data": "You have been removed from Kudo mailing list for account: bob@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        "Subject": {
            "Charset": "UTF-8",
            "Data": "Kudo email removal"
        }
    },
    "ReplyToAddresses": [],
    "Source": "donotreply@kudo.io"
}
```